# Java - Can't find and load a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

For some reason, although I have already downloaded the CSV files, my program is unable to read them. My code is below, and it checks if the CSV file exists. If it does not, it goes to the URL and downloads and reads the code. However, it always re-downloads the code although it is in the path folder.

```
 private void loadData(String path, String url) throws IOException{

    File f = new File(path);
    System.out.println("looking for path " + path);
    if(f.exists()) { 
        readSavedFile(path); //method to load data
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Need to download from internet");
        downloadAndRead(url, path);
    }
```

}

This code outputs

looking for path C:\Users\n_000\workspace\Program\GOOG.csv
Need to download from internet.
looking for path C:\Users\n_000\workspace\Program\CHK.csv
Need to download from internet.

The code that I'm using to create the path is this:

```
        String save = "filename"; //in program use this is the name of the stock eg GOOG or CHK
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String savedFolder = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\";

        path = savedFolder+save+".csv";
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a `C:\Users\n_000\workspace\Program\GOOG.csv` ?

Comment: exists() can return false for various reasons such as permissions or if the call fails.

Comment: @RC. I'm positive that the file exists

Comment: @dustin.schultz I'm on my windows 8 side, and I don't think there should be any issues with permissions.

Comment: can you create a file in the same path using your app?

Comment: @Lian the files such as C:\Users\n_000\workspace\Program\GOOG.csv were created by the app. If the file doesn't exist, it downloads the file from the internet and saves it to C:\Users\n_000\workspace\Program

Comment: it's C:\\ in windows no?

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: @jonbon as mentioned, check the permissions of the directory and the file

Comment: @Lian I'm on windows. I right clicked my workspace folder and clicked on properties and security. Permissions for system are full. Do I need to add some exception for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine,i didn't see any issues,i am posting my tested code,hope it may be useful.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Test test=new Test();
    }
    public Test() 
    {   
        String save = "GOOG"; //in program use this is the name of the stock eg GOOG or CHK
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
        String savedFolder = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\";
        String path = savedFolder+save+".csv";
        String url=null;

        try 
        {
            loadData(path,url);

        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private  void loadData(String path, String url) throws IOException
    {    
        File f = new File(path);
        System.out.println("looking for path " + path);
        if(f.exists()) { 
            readSavedFile(path); //method to load data
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Need to download from internet");
            downloadAndRead(url, path);
        }
    }
    public  void readSavedFile(String path)
    {
        System.out.println("Reading file");
    }

    public  void downloadAndRead(String url,String path)
    {
        System.out.println("Downloding file");
    }
}
```